# is there a way to script GDB with python or c program?

Tags: gdb

I want to write a script that will read a process memory, and display its contents with some modification/format.
It would be create if i could run a c program inside gdb and send gdb commands from this program. Do you know if it is possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possibe, many ide do this. Need to open process with handling process input/output/error streams. Read and analize outputs stream and put your command to input stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would be great if i could run a c program inside gdb and send gdb commands from this program.

That's easy:

```
(gdb) shell /tmp/a.out > /tmp/gdb.script
(gdb) source /tmp/gdb.script
```

If your gdb is built with Python support, much better scripting support is available. Start [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html).

Comment: In fact i want more interaction. In your case, the a.out c program generates commands and then run once. But i will look if it is better with your Python link